# Connecting to two Networks with different DHCP servers

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, network-adapter

Ok,  So at home I have two wired Networks (one with internet access and one that doesn't)

I have Multiple Network adapters on my PC and I want to use one into one network and another to the other network.

The problem I am having (and this was to be expected) is that because both networks have separate routers acting as DHCP Servers, the PC when connected to both gets a bit confused when trying to access web addresses (presumably because of DNS issues).

I want to be able to access the internet through one adapter, and connect to multiple file storage servers/NAS/etc through the other.

Is there anyway to do this (i.e set all web requests to go through one adapter)?

(Also OS = Windows)

Comment: Do you have to make use of DHCP on both networks? Setting one or both NICs to a static IP might make this a lot easier.

Comment: @Hennes Sorry, what do you mean?  Both Networks require DHCP servers on them,

Comment: But your PC does not require using those DHCP servers. Windows has the options 'automatic' (aka DHCP) and manual/static IP. You could pick an IP not used on the network (and not handed out by the relevant DHCP server) and manually set that IP on your computer. When doing this manually or are also asked to enter the DNS servers. Only enter them for one NIC.

Comment: @Hennes Would that work?  Is it that simple?

Comment: Yes and no. It is that simple to access both networks. The LAN NIC gets an IP for one LAN and a route to that LAN. The other Internet facecing NIC gets that LANs IP, netmask and the default gateway. That means it can also reach the DNS servers on that part and access the Internet. (which means the PCs/SANs/printers/... on the other net need to be accessed by IP, not by name).

Comment: If you also want to resolve names for local hosts (e.g. you have a fileserver called MyFIleserver.local' on the inside LAN and you want to use that by name) then you want to set up your own DNS server). And if you want to forward traffic between those networks then you also must take more steps.  But just accessing both networks: Yes, that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are missing is a catch all route to your router that actually routes to your ISPs modem and eventually out to the Internet.

Open up an elevated command prompt and type in "print add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 [x.x.x.x]" where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the Internet facing router. Press enter to execute the command and your computer will now automatically route any requests outside of the two subnets it's directly connected to that IP.